# Not understanding logic behind type syntax, in F#

Tags: f#

let's take this very simple type:

```
type Test() =

    let mutable myBool = false

    member this.SetBool(value) =
        myBool <- value

    member this.GetBool() =
        myBool
```

The boolean *myBool* is part of the instance and yet, it is not referred to by 'this', however, the members have to be referred to by 'this'.

So, to me it looks like there are 3 situations covering 2 cases:

- static, where the data / method is not part of the instance
- prefixed with 'this' where the data / method is part of the instance
- not prefixed by 'this' and the data / method is still part of the instance

The data *is* or *is not* part of the type instance, so why 3 syntaxes?

I'm sure there is a logical reason, but from my perspective (doing a bit of F# here and there), I completely fail to see the logic from a syntax homogeneity point of view (and 'val' is a whole other topic I don't get, despite having gotten some explanations)

Comment: What makes you think `myBool` is part of the instance? It looks to me like it's just a variable that's closed over.

Comment: let a = Test(); let b = Test(); a.SetBool(true); a.GetBool(), b.GetBool() will return true, false. a and b do not share it, so it is part of the instance. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: @glennsl The documentation says "A let binding that is not static is called **an instance let binding**. Instance let bindings execute when objects are created.": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/let-bindings-in-classes

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov That still doesn't make it *part of the instance* though, but I can definitely see how that name could cause confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can see the `myBool` variable as something that is defined in the constructor, when the object is created, and then it is closed over and it becomes implicitly available in the body of the object. In a sense, it is the same as defining a variable in a function, which then returns another function:

```
let test = 
    let mutable myBool = false
    (fun () -> 
        myBool <- not myBool
        myBool)
```

The use of `this` when defining members is needed because those are defined *while* the object is being constructed and so you need some way of making the recursive reference to the object currently being constructed.

Having `this.MemberName` has one practical advantage, which is that it limits the scope of those recursive references - so you cannot accidentally write code that references `this` before the object has been fully initialized (which could happen if you could use `this` in the constructor).

So, I think the fact that you can refer to `myBool` is quite aligned with the standard functional programming ideas (such as variable scoping and capturing). F# combines functional programming with OOP and the way you use `this` is coming from the OOP world.

Comment: so, if I understand, using 'this' allows access to the object only once it has been initialized? I always assumed the method prefixed with this were just the public ones.

Comment: The point was that `this` can only be accessed inside methods - and methods can only be called on the object once it has been initialized.